# PLY - escaping new line in C-style comments

Tags: ply

I'm writing a simple parser using PLY. My comments can look like this

```
# this is a single line comment \
with an escaped new line
```

My attempt is to use states here. I have

```
states = (
    ('COMMENT', 'exclusive'),
)
tokens = ('COMMENT')

def t_begin_COMMENT(t):
    r'\#'
    t.lexer.begin('COMMENT')


def t_COMMENT_contents(t):
    r'.|\\\n'


t_COMMENT_ignore = r' '

def t_COMMENT_error(t):
    pass


def t_COMMENT_end(t):
    r'\n'
    t.lexer.begin('INITIAL')
```

When I do

```
lexer = lex.lex()
string = "# test \\\ns \n4"
lexer.input(string)
for tok in lexer:
    print(tok)
```

it should print 4 (I have another token for that, but it's irrelevant now) but I get `s` and `4` where `s` is still a comment. How do I write regex for content? Is this because `COMMENT` ends with `\n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python regular expressions do not produce the longest match. Alternation (`|`) in a Python regular expression is *ordered*; if you use the pattern `.|\\\n`, then `.` will always match (unless the string is empty), and so `\\\n` will never be tried. This is easier to see without the escape symbols:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'.|ab', 'ab')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>
>>> re.match(r'ab|.', 'ab')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='ab'>
```

It's not at all clear to me why you want to go to all that work, rather than using a single regular expression without having to resort to lexer states.

```
def t_comment(t):
    r'\#(\\\n|.)*\n'
    pass
```

(Note: I would prefer the regular expression `r'\#(\\[\s\S]|.)*'`, which allows a `\` to escape anything, including itself. The regex you use doesn't allow you to ever put a backslash at the end of a comment line:

```
# This will continue, perhaps unexpectedly: \\
still a comment
```

Also, the trailing `\n` will be ignored anyway, so there's no obvious reason to include it in the pattern, where it might fail to match if the comment is right at the end of the input and the input doesn't terminate with a newline.

Comment: I'm used to states because mainly I use Flex. Thanks for the clarification, I didn't know it alteration was ordered.

Comment: @Awerde: I would use exactly the same regular expression in flex. There's no point using states just to avoid repetition operators.

Comment: Of course, in Flex you don't need to worry about ordered alternation. That's a "gotcha" with Python and other Perl-compatible regex engines. I believe Javascript is the same. Flex regular expressions use Posix rules (the same as grep), where alternation is not ordered.